# Is parent view and container view the same thing?

Tags: android, view

I'm confused about the definition. In Android, is a view's parent and container the same thing? For instance, when a recyclerview layout contains a itemview, is the recyclerview both the itemview's parent view and container view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> view's parent and container the same thing?

Yes. Since only containers can contain other views (incl. other containers too), then only said container can be parent to views it contains.

> recyclerview layout contains a itemview, is the recyclerview both the itemview's parent view and container view

recyclerview is not the best example, but for simplicity 'yes'. This may give you some overview too:

```
containerA
   view1
   containerB
      view2
      view3
```

where `containerA`/`B` are ViewGroups (i.e. LinearLayouts) and `view1`/`2`/`3` are i.e. widgets (say Buttons).